# How to fetch data from different tables with current date condition?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table called WB.Email, WB.DATA and WB.APRIOD.
I have to fetch the data from WB.Email condition is: where **current date = display date -15 days ;**

To find the display date use table WB.DATA, select the date column where valid = 'Y' with the other condition (select PERIOD FROM WB.APRIOD WHERE VALID ='Y')

CVALID = 'V' and current date = session start date - 15 days

What would be the final query ?

WB.Email :

| PERIOD | HSID | CVALID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | V |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | V |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | V |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | V |

WB.DATA table

| PERIOD | HSID | SDATE | START |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | 2022-03-11 | N |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | 2022-03-10 | Y |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| 2022-09-15 | 183 | 2022-01-05 | Y |

WB.APRIOD:

| PERIOD | VALID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-15 | Y |
| 2021-09-15 | N |
| 2020-09-15 | N |
| 2029-09-15 | N |

Expected Result: for example current date is 24-02-22 and session start date i.e SDATE column in WB.DATA table is 2022-03-10 then result should come like below table.

| PERIOD | HSID | CVALID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | V |
| 2022-09-15 | 184 | V |

Comment: Not entirely clear how things are linking here, likely can be accomplished by using a subquery as the joins to both the WB.APRIOD and WB.DATA tables.

Comment: WB.APRIOD is used for get the current valid period i.e in subquery it will be use as (select  period FROM WB.APRIOD where valid ='Y')

Comment: can you add result you want. so will give the right solution.

Comment: I want to get the result as : select * from WB.cvalid = 'V' and current date = SDATE - 15 days

Comment: And SDATE only it select when START column should be 'Y'

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. I.e [mcve].

Comment: @RohiniKumari you get answered ?

Comment: Hi Piyush, I am checking your query in database.

Comment: NOT WORKING. " 1) [Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  No authorized routine named "GETDATE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-440", SQLSTATE "42884" and message tokens "GETDATE|FUNCTION".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29"

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT * FROM WB.EMAIL E
LEFT JOIN WB.DATA D ON E.PERIOD = D.PERIOD
LEFT JOIN WB.APRIOD A ON D.PERIOD = A.PERIOD
WHERE E.CVALID = 'V'
AND D.START = 'Y'
AND GETDATE() = DATEADD(DAY,-15,D.SDATE)
```

here result show only Email table if you want diff column then right down your column name.

Comment: Hi @Piyush, I tried by using subquery and it is fetching the correct data. could you please help me to convert in JOIN query. here is the query:                                      
       Select * from WBXHSAV.INSCRT WHERE CVALID = 'V' AND HSESID IN (
Select HSESID from WBXHSAV.SESDAT WHERE CSTART = 'Y' AND DPERIOD IN (select DPERIOD from WBXHSAV.PERIOT WHERE CVALID = 'Y' ) 
        AND DJOUR = (CURRENT DATE  + 14 DAYS)
   )

Comment: use this `Select * from WBXHSAV.INSCRT 
WHERE CVALID = 'V' 
AND HSESID IN ( Select HSESID from WBXHSAV.SESDAT WHERE CSTART = 'Y') 
AND DPERIOD IN (select DPERIOD from WBXHSAV.PERIOT WHERE CVALID = 'Y' ) 
AND DJOUR = (CURRENT DATE + 14 DAYS) `

Comment: please vote your right answered for other user see that.